# Does Allah speak to people directly?

Tags: allah, jinn

I have a relative, who has recently been claiming that Allah (S.A.W) is directly speaking to him.

He was a muslim, but non-practicing. Suddenly he has changed and he started praying, fasting, and is also memorising the Qur'an.

But the problem is that he is doing things to an extreme level. He left his job and is now saying that he can find the cures of cancer or ebola and is saying many other things which does not seem as normal behaviour. Plus for this his wife and children are very concerned.

So I wanted to know if Allah does speak to people?

Please let me know what the Quran has to say about this.

Comment: Did you ask  him what Allah (swt) has been telling him? Ask him questions, ask him about the environment of the supposed direct communication, ask him about the medium of communication, is it verbal? Symbols? Visions? These questions will not only help you get to the truth, but also help him/her get a clear picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Quran sura 42:51. Allah does not talk to a human being by direct means. It is however possible to see aspiring dreams etc.

Allah has also made family a responsibility. Providing family with sustenance and good education/training and not turning them away from religion is also a responsibility from Allah see Quran 66:6.

Tell you relative that if his change is from Allah, it must be balanced (Quran 2:143). If he is escaping from his family responsibilities in the name of excessive worship, it must be from Shaitan because the Prophet (pbuh) prohibited his companion Abdullah bin Amr bin Aas from ignoring his wife for the sake of excessive worship.

Answer (score 2):

We believe the chain of communication between Allah and his creation is as follows:

Allah -> Angel Jibreel (Gabriel) -> Prophet -> people

Now Allah honored Musa(Moses) by speaking to him directly, but once again he was still a Prophet.

After Prophet Muhammad(saw) passed away, there is no new revelation to come.

The only thing that is left that resembles prophethood are dreams. Prophet Muhammad said that dreams a 1/46th revelation. Meaning someone may experience or see something that is from Allah, but the scholars say it has limits. Meaning no new revelation comes through dreams. So if someone says that Allah spoke to them in a dream and that they don't have to pray anymore, that was not a true dream. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Thnx, that was helpful...pls pray :)

Answer (score 0):

God did not speak directly with any of his creation except for twice: The first was with Moses, and the second was with Mohammed.

They have heard Him but did not see Him, because He speaks from behind a veil of light

Comment: The question is asking for a Qur'anic basis: This answer would be much stronger if it had Qur'anic references to back any of it up.

Comment: وما كان لبشر أن يكلمه الله إلا وحيا أو من وراء  الشورى الاية 53

Answer (score -1):

You should ask yourself whether God has ever spoken to anyone directly? If God has spoken to the prophets or saints, then why not your friend, is your friend different from any one of those people?

You should know that God works in mysterious ways and it is entirely possible that God is speaking to him. However I would go on the assumption that God is not, and your friend needs medical help.

Comment: As the evidences suggest that God has only spoken directly to Prophets only, I believe it is better to seek medical help before reaching any conclusion...anyways thnx, pls pray :)

Comment: The question is asking for a Qur'anic basis; as written, this appears to be speculation based on insufficient information rather than any practical *answer*.